# UDP server crashes when receiving datagram

Tags: udp, dart

I'm discovering Dart language. To train myself, I try to code a simple UDP server that logs every datagram received.

Here's my code so far:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class UDPServer {
  static final UDPServer _instance = new UDPServer._internal();

  // Socket used by the server.
  RawDatagramSocket _udpSocket;

  factory UDPServer() {
    return _instance;
  }

  UDPServer._internal();

  /// Starts the server.
  Future start() async {
      await RawDatagramSocket
          .bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, Protocol.udpPort, reuseAddress: true)
          .then((RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
        _udpSocket = udpSocket;
        _udpSocket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
          switch (event) {
            case RawSocketEvent.READ:
              _readDatagram();
              break;
            case RawSocketEvent.CLOSED:
              print("Connection closed.");
              break;
          }
        });
      });
  }

  void _readDatagram() {
    Datagram datagram = _udpSocket.receive();

    if (datagram != null) {
      String content = new String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data).trim();
      String address = datagram.address.address;

      print('Received "$content" from $address');
    }
  }
}
```

It works partially great... After logging some messages, it just crashes. The number varies between 1 and ~5. And IDEA just logs `Lost connection to device.`, nothing more. I tried to debug but didn't find anything.

Does anyone have an idea why it crashes? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention but I was using this code into a Flutter application and it seems to come from that. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11260) for more info.

Comment: When you run from command line, do you see any exceptions?

Comment: @SethLadd it seems to be Flutter related. See my edit